# Jenkins Pipeline job to fetch another jenkins job build status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline Job , which need to monitor the another Jenkins job (say JobA) current build and publish the status (Build Status : Success or Failure) in current pipeline stage. How to achieve that. 
The job(JobA) will not be triggered from the pipeline job. It will run Independently. From Pipeline job , need to fetch the status of JobA.

Answer (score 2):

To get the last build result of Job A:

```
jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem("JobA").lastBuild.result
```

Unclear what exactly you mean by "monitor", but you may get build number of "lastBuild" and watch if it has changed.

Comment: how to use the above line in the Jenkins pipeline script?